# Maven reporting: show compiler warning

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

Is there any maven plugin that can show compiler warning in the site report?

So someone/pm/or manager can check the compiler warning report.

Thanks...

Comment: Try to add `<showWarnings>true</showWarnings>` to the `maven-compiler-plugin`. I think this is all you need.

Comment: Since when pm/manager care about compiler warnings? :)

Comment: And where does <showWarnings>true</showWarnings> go in the plugin settings?